# (Maven project) Could not find or load main class "class"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I was following a tutorial of spring and everything was working fine till i clone my project, now the cloned project and the original project dont want to work, i already searched trough whole stack overflow similar questions and i was not able to solve the issue, i already cleaned the project, restarted eclipse, updated, added and removed dependencys from the pom.xml and nothing seems to work.

**Here is my Main class:**

```
    package com.caveofprogramming.spring.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.Offer;
import com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.OfferDAO;


public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/beans/beans.xml");

        OfferDAO offersDao = (OfferDAO) context.getBean("offerDao");



        try {

            List<Offer> offers= new ArrayList<Offer>();
            offers.add(new Offer(1,"Pepito", "pepito@tcs.com", "i know css and html5"));
            offers.add(new Offer(2, "Juancito", "juancito@tcs.com", "i know about rest and play"));
            offers.add(new Offer(3, "Juancho Tazo", "jtazo@tcs.com", "im an expert on SPEL and SQL!"));

            if(offersDao.Create(offers).length==offers.size()){

                for (int i = 0; i < offers.size(); i++) {

                    System.out.println(offers.get(i).getName()+" record was created succesfully");

                }

                System.out.println("All the new records were created succesfully");

            }

            else{
                System.out.println("One or more of the records were not createdS");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();

    }

}
```

**Beans.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">    

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.caveofprogramming.spring.test" />
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="com/caveofprogramming/spring/props/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />




</beans>
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.caveofprogramming.spring.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tutorial-5</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>




  </dependencies>
</project>
```

so as i said, everything started failing when i copy pasted the project on my same workspace, of course i changed the name.

This error i get it after doing a maven clean.

if i dont do that, i get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/beans/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.registerTransactionalEventListenerFactory(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:92)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory.html) its added since 4.2, try to update all spring dependencies in pom.xml to `4.2.5.RELEASE`.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, i updated all the spring dependencies to the 4.0 version and it works now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the class EventListenerFactory.
Its defined in the maven 
artefact 
org.springframework
spring-context

add a dependency to this artefact in your pom.xml
Use the same version, as for your other spring artefacts.

Comment: Hi, it seems that the error appears when i try to add the schemas for the tx namespace.

Like, on the beans.xml, when i add:

xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

and

xsi:schemaLocation=http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd

when i remove them, the program works fine again, but when i add them back, the program throws the error mentioned on the OP.